# How to prove $a \ln(b) \sqrt{b} > b \ln(a) \sqrt{a}$ for $a,b > 0$ and $a>b$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Visually, it is easy to see that the inequality holds for $a \neq b$ and $a,b > 0$. Do note that I'm only considering $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ so I may miss something if they were real numbers.

I did think earlier about the inequality $\ln(x) < \sqrt{x}$ but I don't know how to prove $\ln(x)\sqrt{x} < x$, which I think would help.

Comment: The inequality doesn't hold. If $b=1$, then LHS $=0$, RHS $> 0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The inequality holds iff
$$
\frac {\ln(b)} {\sqrt{b}} > \frac {\ln(a)} {\sqrt{a}}.
$$
Let $f(t)=\frac{\ln(t)}{\sqrt{t}}$. This function is slowly decreasing after a certain $x$, so for a large $b$ we get the result (you can compute $f'$ to see this). Otherwise, if $b$ is small enough, let's say $b=1$, we have $a>1$ and $a<1$ if the inequality still holds, which is absurd.

Comment: Can you show how this is true? As in, how it constrains the inequality in the question.

Comment: @KaiserHaz You have $f'(t) \le 0 \iff t \ge e^{2}$, so the inequality holds for $b\ge e^2$.

Comment: Ok I understand that. But how did you get $\frac{\ln(b)}{\sqrt{b}} > \frac{\ln(a)}{\sqrt{a}}$?

Comment: @KaiserHaz: just divide both sides by $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality doesn't hold. If $b=1$, then LHS=0, RHS > 0.